# Why is the CSS for an a tag inside an li tag causing the li to not expand vertically to contain its content?

Tags: html, css

I have a `<div>` with the ID `#left`, which cotnains another `<div>` with the ID `#container`. Inside `#container` is a `<ul>`.

I thought the default would be that the `<li>` would vertically expand to contain any and all text inside it. But it doesn't. This is the CSS:

```
#left {
    width:200px;
}
#container {
    margin: 0 6px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#container li {
    background:greenyellow;
    position: relative;
    border: #BF0000 thin solid;
    margin: 0 0 12px 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    clear:both;
}
#container li:hover {
    background: #ffffff;
}
#container a {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

By [using jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jBvQ8/5/), I've discovered that it's the `<a>` tag, and something about it's CSS properties that is breaking my `<li>` tag's height. However, if I change the `<a>`, I lose the other effect I want, which is to be able to click anywhere in the `<li>` and have it activate the link.

Can I get the `<li>` to expand vertically and also the `<a>` tag to fill the entire `<li>`? I don't see why the `<a>` should impact the `<li>` the way it's doing right now.

Comment: Why are you absolutely positioning the `a` element? http://jsfiddle.net/jBvQ8/6/

Comment: @steveax: Note in your jsFiddle that if you remove the absolute positioning, the link is no longer clickable.

Comment: That's because there are no links to click in the first place. Adding `href="#"` to all the `a` elements, even to the fiddle linked by @steveax, makes them respond to clicks just fine.

Comment: If you mean the greenyellow background of the list items doesn't act like a link, then the simplest solution is to move all the CSS from the `li` to the `a` (and remove `position: absolute` and `clear: both` because they are superfluous).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What i understand that you want to have your li to wrap your a tag properly while a tag can grow its height based on content. if this is the case please visit http://jsfiddle.net/jBvQ8/16/ for solution.

If you need some modification or other use case to handle i will update that jsfiddle of mine.

```
#left {
    width:200px;
}
#container {
    margin: 0 6px;
}

#container li {
    background:greenyellow;
    position: relative;
    border: #BF0000 thin solid;
    margin: 0 0 12px 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    clear:both;
}
#container li:hover {
    background: #ffffff;
}
#container a {
    display:block;    
    width: 100%;


}
```

Comment: I added [`href=#"` into your jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jBvQ8/18/), and it works exactly as I hoped. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure what you want, but maybe you want entire `<a>` to be inside li with the applied CSS.

simply remove `position:absolute` from the css of `anchor` tag i.e.

```
#container a {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jBvQ8/7/)

and if you want a `pointer` cursor, when you hover your `li` with `anchor`, simply specify href tag(even `href='#'`) to the anchors

see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jBvQ8/9/) for clickable anchors

Comment: why keep top, left, width and height?

Comment: I cannot say that, he might have some global css or parent container css, making him do that. I just modified the original class content with its position attribute, rest as before.

Comment: As mentioned in the comments on the question, removing the absolute positioning causes the LI tag to no longer be clickable.

Comment: read my answer completely, to make it clickable, you have to specify href attribute of the anchor tag @DaveMG

Comment: That's a little better, but, note that in my original example you can click anywhere in the li tag within its border. In yours, you have to hover over the link text.

Comment: see my latest fiddle in my answer, you still can click anywhere on the li tag, as the anchor tag occupies its entire space. Also if you want to make your li clickable, simply give it a style cursor:pointer and bind its onclick event and do watever you want to i.e. navigation to other page through javascript. you get the idea though right?

Comment: I'Ve edited the [jsFiddle to make it more clear](http://jsfiddle.net/jBvQ8/14/). In mine, you can *click* anywhere in the LI tag and activate the LI, but the heights are wrong. In yours, the heights are right, but the link doesn't cover the whole LI.

Comment: then give your anchors exactly the same dimension as you have given to LIs

Comment: @ManishMishra - Part of the question is how to get the anchors to have the same dimensions as the LI's, and your answer is "just do that then"..